Microsoft Access Database Query Criteria Not Working
Currently I'm making a simple database a company to sort their documents into clauses specified by BRCGS standards. The documents are listed like the following examples "QUA 012.2, PRO 034.1, Misc 044.1, etc." I have been trying for the life of me to get a query working where I can just get the Misc documents, but it is not working.
Here's what I've tried:
SELECT Documents.document_id, Documents.title, Documents.link, Documents.description
FROM Documents
WHERE (((Documents.title) Like "%Misc%"));

As well as many different configurations, like putting QUA in there. Nothing has worked except a specific entry, such as QUA 012.1. That's the only thing that has worked. Other than that specific test, no results show up at all, just a blank line for adding an entry into the query. If anyone can help this I would greatly appreciate it. I've tried to use both the SQL view and design view, but nothing is working. Thanks!

Use "*" instead of "%" as a wildcard

Another option is to keep the % wildcard and use ALike instead of Like ---> ALike "%Misc%"

The issue of which wildcards for which context is sort of an Access FAQ topic.  Similar posts
